# How to recursively discretize segments if segment length is higher than a specific value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, euclidean-distance

In order to improve the efficiency of a python script, I am trying to convert a script based on a lot of "for loop" operations on a points cloud thanks to Numpy to speed up the process.

[image: Points Cloud overview and some euclidean distance representation]

In a nutshell, I have a 3d model represented as a set of 3d points (x,y,z coordinates) contained in a np.array (dimension : (188706, 3))

```
[[168.998 167.681   0.]    <-- point 1
 [169.72  167.695   0.]    <-- point 2
 [170.44  167.629   0.]    <-- point 3
 ...
 [148.986 163.271  25.8]    <-- point 188704
 [148.594 163.634  25.8]    <-- point 188705
 [148.547 163.667  25.8]]   <-- point 188706
```

Each pair of [[row *x*-1][row *x*]] represents a segment in 3D

```
[[168.998 167.681   0.]    [169.72  167.695   0.]    <-- SEGMENT 1 (points 1 & 2)
 [169.72  167.695   0.]    [170.44  167.629   0.]    <-- SEGMENT 2 (points 2 & 3)
 [170.44  167.629   0.]    [171.149 167.483   0.]    <-- SEGMENT 3 (points 3 & 4)
 ...
 [149.328 162.853  25.8]   [148.986 163.271  25.8]    <-- SEGMENT 94351 (points 188703 & 188704)
 [148.986 163.271  25.8]   [148.594 163.634  25.8]    <-- SEGMENT 94352 (points 18874 & 188705)
 [148.594 163.634  25.8]   [148.547 163.667  25.8]]   <-- SEGMENT 94353 (points 188705 & 188706)
```

My goal is to measure the euclidean distance between each ordered points//pair of rows(= the length of each segments) so that I can detect where I need to add more points to represent a bit more the surface of my 3d model. In other words, if the segment length is above a threshold value (=0.5mm), I will have to discretize this particular segment with more points and to add those additional points in my points cloud.

I've found a way to measure the euclidean distance recurcively between each rows thanks to this code:

```
EuclidianDistance = np.linalg.norm(PtCloud[:-1] - PtCloud[1:],axis=1)
```

Which gives this result:

```
[0.72213572 0.72301867 0.72387637 ... 0.54008148 0.5342593  0.05742822]
```

And I found as well how to descretize a segment according to its vertices (extremities):

```
def AddEquidistantPoints(p1, p2, parts):
    return np.stack((np.linspace(p1[0], p2[0], parts + 1), np.linspace(p1[1], p2[1], parts + 1)), axis=-1)

if EuclidianDistance > 0.5mm:
    dist = AddEquidistantPoints(currentRow, previousRow, 10) #10 --> nb subdivisions
```

But my first issue is those euclidean distances have only to be computed on points where z coordinates are equals. Have I to split my array when z coordinate are not equals ?
With :

```
PtCloud = np.split(PtCloud, np.where(np.diff(PtCloud[:,2])!=0)[0]+1)
```

Which gives me a list of arrays so I suppose I will have unfortunately to use a for loop...

Here is the proper behavior represented with Excel:[image]

And my second problem is related to the recurcive check and discretization step since I don't know how to implement it with this particular case. I wonder if there is a way to do it without any for loops.

So I would be very delighted if anyone could help me solve this challenge as I am currently "stuck".
It starts to be very challenging for me.

Thanks in advance,
Hervé

Answer (score 0):

Just to share with you, I've just found a way to solve my problem. It is probably not the most efficient way to do that but it works.

```
import numpy as np

print("====================")
print("Initial Points Cloud")
print("====================")

POINTCLOUD = np.array([[168.998, 167.681, 0.],
                       [169.72, 167.695,  0.],
                       [170.44, 167.629,  0.],
                       [171.149, 167.483,  0.],
                       [150.149, 167.483,  4.2],
                       [160.149, 167.483,  4.2],
                       [159.149, 166.483,  4.2],
                       [152.149, 157.483,  7.],
                       [149.328, 162.853, 25.8],
                       [148.986, 163.271, 25.8],
                       [148.594, 163.634, 25.8],
                       [180.547, 170.667, 25.8],
                       [200.547, 190.667, 25.8]])
print(POINTCLOUD)


print("============================================")
print("Reshaped Point Cloud in the form of segments")
print("============================================")
a = np.column_stack((POINTCLOUD[:-1],POINTCLOUD[1:]))
print(a)
b = a.reshape((a.shape[0],2, 3))
#print(b)

print("")
print("*******************************")
print("Non filtered euclidean distance")
print("*******************************")
EuclidianDistance = np.transpose(np.linalg.norm(b[:,0] - b[:,1],axis=1))
print(EuclidianDistance)

print("")
print("****************")
print("Mask computation")
print("****************")
mask = np.transpose([a[:,2] == a[:,5]])
mask2 = [a[:,:] == a[:,:]]*np.transpose([a[:,2] == a[:,5]])



print("")
print(mask2)

print("")
print("***********************************")
print("1rst Filter applyed on points cloud")
print("***********************************")

# b = np.where(mask2,a,0)
# b = np.squeeze(b, axis=0)
b = np.squeeze(np.where(mask2,a,0), axis=0)
print(b)
print("")

b2 = b[np.squeeze(mask2,axis=0),...].reshape((np.sum(mask),b.shape[1]))
print(b2)
print("")
#print(b2.reshape(b2.shape[0],2, 3))

b = b2.reshape(b2.shape[0],2, 3)


print("")
print("***************************************")
print("FIRST EUCLIDEAN DISTANCE FILTERING STEP")
print("***************************************")
EuclidianDistance = np.linalg.norm(b[:,0] - b[:,1],axis=1)
print(EuclidianDistance)

print("")
print("***************************")
print("# THRESHOLD MASK GENERATION")
print("***************************")
threshold = 7
mask_threshold = np.transpose(EuclidianDistance>threshold)
print(mask_threshold)

print("")
print("**********************************")
print("# FINAL FILTERED ECLIDEAN DISTANCE")
print("**********************************")
EuclidianDistance = EuclidianDistance[np.squeeze(mask_threshold),...]
print(EuclidianDistance)

print("")
print("**********************")
print("SEGMENTS TO DISCRETIZE")
print("**********************")
SegmentToDiscretize = b[np.squeeze(mask_threshold),...]
print(SegmentToDiscretize)



print("")
print("******************************")
print("EQUIDISTANT POINTS COMPUTATION")
print("******************************")

nbsubdiv2 = np.transpose(np.ceil(np.array(np.divide(EuclidianDistance,0.7))).astype(int)).reshape((SegmentToDiscretize.shape[0],1))
print(nbsubdiv2)
print(nbsubdiv2.shape)
print(nbsubdiv2[1,0])

print(SegmentToDiscretize.shape)
print(SegmentToDiscretize[:,0])


nbsubdiv = [10,30,10]

addedpoint = np.linspace(SegmentToDiscretize[:,0],SegmentToDiscretize[:,1],nbsubdiv[0], dtype = np.float)
addedpoint = addedpoint.reshape((addedpoint.shape[0]*addedpoint.shape[1],3))
print(np.sort(addedpoint,axis=0))


print("")
print("***********************************")
print("UPDATED POINT CLOUD WITH NEW POINTS")
print("***********************************")
# duplicates are removed with the command np.unique
POINTCLOUD = np.unique(np.append(POINTCLOUD,addedpoint, axis=0),axis=0)
print(POINTCLOUD)

print("")
print("************************")
print("FINAL SORTED POINT CLOUD")
print("************************")
sortedPOINTCLOUD = POINTCLOUD[np.argsort(POINTCLOUD[:, 2])]
print(sortedPOINTCLOUD)
print("***************************")
```

Please do not hesitate to add your own proposal to improve it if you want. It will be very welcome !